# Not enough values to unpack(expected 2, got 1) using odeint

Tags: python

I have been trying to numerically solve the Rayleigh Plesset equation. I have written

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# define equations
def equation(y0, t):
    R, u = y0
    f = [u, 1/(R*rho)*(4*miu*u/R-2*sigma/R)-3*u**2/(2*R)]

    return f

def plot_results(time, R_1):
    plt.plot(time, R_1)

    s = "for initial radius" + str(R_0)
    plt.title("Oscillations in Sonoluinescing Bubble Radius" + s)
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.yalbel("Radius of bubble")
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

# parameters
time = np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.025)
rho = 1000
sigma = 0.0725
miu = 0.001
P_v = 2330
P_0 = 100000
P_ext = 70000*np.sin(2*np.pi*31700*time)

# initial conditions
R_0 = 0.01

R_1 = odeint(equation, [R_0], time)

plot_results(time, R_1)
```

However, when I run the code I found the following error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).

Comment: What line of code is the error occurring?

Comment: You didn't pass in a value for `u`. `y0` is supposed to be a pair. (R, u)

Comment: @LPython It is occurring at line 7

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. You need to provide a [mre] including the full error message with traceback. See [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: I was using this video as a reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eZyTNthJG4. He didn't pass in a value for u (which in the video is x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line of code;

`R, u = y0`

You are attempting to set 2 variables in one line, however only providing one value.

You need to set 2 values or only assign one variable here.

`R, u = y0, 1` as an example.

Comment: I was using this video as a reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eZyTNthJG4. Also, y0 is a vector, so it contains two components, so I don't see where this is going wrong.

Comment: Is `y0` only one value? I assume it's `[R_0]` from `odeint(equation, [R_0], time)`, but I'm not familiar with `scipy.integrate.odeint`. OP needs to provide a [mre] with traceback.

Comment: R_0 is the initial condition for the variable R. Essentially, u is the derivative of R with respect to time, and I defined the vector y0 to be the vector with components R and u.

Comment: @KoutaDagnino in the video, he passes 2 variables as a list to the equations function, you only pass one. I suggest you review the video and see what you should be passing `R_1 = odeint(equation, [R_0], time)`

Comment: So R and u aren't seen as two different variables?

Comment: They are, you're only passing one variable to equation here `R_1 = odeint(equation, [R_0], time)` In the video, the user passes 2 variables as a list. `R_1 = odeint(equation, [theta0, x0], time)`

Comment: Aaaaah, got it. I have to insert a boundary condition for u as well. Hopefully it works...

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
So I have passed in two variables to the equation, and the code looks like this:

'''
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    from scipy.integrate import odeint

```
# define equations
def equation(y0, t):
    R, u = y0
    return u, (P_g-P_0-70000*np.sin(2*np.pi*31700*t)-4*miu*u/R- 2*sigma/R)/(R*rho)-3*u**2/(2*R)

def plot_results(time, R_1):
    plt.plot(time, R_1)

    s = "for initial radius" + str(R_0)
    plt.title("Oscillations in Sonoluminescing Bubble Radius" + s)
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("Radius of bubble")
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

# parameters
time = np.arange(0, 0.0001, 0.000000000025)
rho = 1000
sigma = 0.0725
miu = 0.001
P_g = 2330
P_0 = 10000

# initial conditions
R_0 = 0.0001
u_0 = 0

R_1 = odeint(equation, [R_0, u_0], time)

plot_results(time, R_1)
```

However, when i run the code I get a a useless graph which doesn't make any sense at all. I've used the parameters as defined here: https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/asho/AdvCompMech/Assignment_1.pdf

Any suggestions?